# Applying voltage across reverse-biased diode

Tags: diodes, pn-junction

I have a theoretical question just about the internal voltage within the diode across the PN junction and how I can view that from a circuit perspective when I apply an external voltage across the diode.

[image]

I understand that when a voltage is applied across the diode in a reversed biased manner, the depletion region expands and the voltage across the PN junction depletion region increases (vo in the diagram).

Is it possible to model the intrinsic voltage across the depletion as a voltage source? If so, how is it possible that we have an external voltage source with a higher voltage connected external. Where is the voltage difference between the two sources being dropped across?

Comment: Does "voltage source" source current as well? If so, it would be something new. If the "voltage source" does not source any current, yes, ex. a Zener diode.

Comment: Are you asking how KVL is satisfied in a diode connected to a voltage source? If so, this is certainly a duplicate.

Comment: @Matt Essentially yes, in particular, how the v0 voltage is dealt with since it will appear when the diode is both forward biased and reverse biased.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/389745/10381